# Socket Listener on Ubuntu with .NET Core

Tags: sockets, .net-core

I have a Socket Listener than runs in a .Net core Console app, my concern is how do I keep this Console app running, I am using supervisor for my Web apps, can I somehow configure supervisor to keep an exe running?

Any suggestions on what would be a better option to write a Socket Listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `service` (or also named Daemon) that will start your .NET Core app when you Ubuntu starts.

Comment: Thanks, that looks simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cron to launch the application as an exe on reboot and then periodically check to see if it is running and launch if not.

You can use the @reboot keyword - from the link below:

```
@reboot /path/to/execuable1
```

*The above example will execute /path/to/executable1 when the system starts.
For more information on special strings enter "man 5 crontab".*

[cron how to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)